# How to do query for '&' by SQL Server Full-text search?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

```
select * from xxx where contains(summary, '"G&B*"')
```

When i do the above search, the '&' was ignored (escaped). Do you know how to do query by Full-Text search to hit 'G&B'?

Thanks.

Comment: What language are you using for your full text index (English, neutral, etc.)? Are you using a stoplist?

Comment: full text index was for english. I have no idea of stoplist? Thanks

Comment: In SSMS, right-click the table and select Full Text Index > Properties and see what Full Text Index Stoplist is set to.

Comment: Keith, I checked my stoplist as you said, it was empty.